# Typescript: Allow undeclared properties, assume undefined

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code example:

```
declare const isDisabled: {reason: string} | false;
const disabledReason: string = isDisabled?.reason || '';
```

The the JavaScript code is perfectly valid and it works in runtime, but with typescript you get this error: "Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'false | { reason: string; }'"

Is there a way to make typescript allow this but interpret "reason" as undefined for the case that the property doesn't exist? (Which is the runtime behavior of JavaScript). I expect the resolved type to be `string | undefined`, and the compilation to pass.

Comment: Your use of the optional chaining operator `?.` here is highly suspect, since your `isDisabled` variable cannot be null or undefined, so this never short-circuits. Your code is equivalent to `isDisabled.reason`, and then it should hopefully be obvious why it is correct that you get a type error here - it would not be very useful if Typescript treated things like `console.log(obj.someTypo)` as correct code that logs "undefined", if `someTypo` is a misspelling of a real property name.

Comment: @kaya3 for some reason I thought that "disabled?.reason" is equivalent to "disabled && disabled.reason". I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own answer to summarize previous comments.

The first thing to understand is that I assumed `isDisabled?.reason` is identical to `isDisabled && isDisabled.reason` but apparently this is not the case, as as @kaya3 pointed out, the optional chaining operators works only for undefined / null values.

So there are two possible solutions here:

1. Adding an explicit condition for the truthiness of isDisabled:

```
isDisabled && isDisabled.reason
```

2. Changing "false" to "null"

```
declare const isDisabled: {reason: string} | null;
const disabledReason: string = isDisabled?.reason || '';
```

What I initially wanted was for typescript to enable something like that:

```
const x = false.reason; // inferred value is undefined
```

But seems like this is not possible and unadvised.

Answer (score 1):

Just be a little more verbose:

```
const disabledReason: string = isDisabled ? isDisabled.reason : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails for two reasons:

1. Because you assign `false` in the statement above, typescript infers that `isDisabled` is always `false`. If you hover `isDisabled` in the second statement you will see `isDisabled: false`.
2. `isDisabled?.reason` doesn't specify that `reason` exists on the object, you first have to cancel out the possibility of it being `false` by using:

`const disabledReason: string = isDisabled ? isDisabled?.reason : '';`

And in complete: (function used because typescript will always infer that `isDisabled` === false otherwise)

```
const isDisabled: {reason: string} | false = false;
const isDisabledWithReason: {reason: string} | false = { reason: 'Aborted' };

function getDisabledReason(a_isDisabled: {reason: string} | false): string {
  return a_isDisabled != false ? a_isDisabled.reason : '';
}

console.log(getDisabledReason(isDisabled)); // ""
console.log(getDisabledReason(isDisabledWithReason)); // "Aborted"
```

Comment: Just a note about avoiding inferred values in Typescript examples - you can write `declare const isDisabled: {reason: string} | false;` without initialising it. A bit simpler than declaring a function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. The problem is actually not related to automatic inference, as it reproduces even when using declare (fixed my question to make it clear). 
You solution of using a ternary is actually something I wanted to avoid to make my code more elegant. I was under the impression that isDisabled?.reason is identical to "isDisabled && isDisabled.reason" but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv Your problem was caused by both reasons - Automatic inference and also wrong propertsy access. As for ternaries, they're just nicer looking `if else` statements, which you need to make sure `isDisabled` isn't `false` but actually `[ reason: string; }`